# Inserción deficiente SQLite - C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, base-de-datos

Tengo que extraer ciertos registros de ficheros csv e insertarlos a mi BD de SQLite, ya me las arregle para obtener los registros pero no he podido encontrar una forma mas o menos eficiente para la inserción de este gran volumen de datos (Son varios millones de registros), el codigo que tengo es este:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrayRespuesta.Length; j++) {
  if (true))
    {
     //CODE    
    }

  if (arrayRespuesta[j].Contains(":") && posLectura.Count > 0)
    {
      string tramaLectura = arrayRespuesta[j];
      string[] arrayTramaLectura = tramaLectura.Split(new[] { "," 
    },StringSplitOptions.None);
    string insertBD = "INSERT INTO 'Sensor'('Id_DL','id_GW','Ch1','Ch2','Ch3','Ch4','Ch5','FechaLectura') VALUES('" + ItemSeleccionado.idDbDataloger + "','" + CredentialsGateway.idGateway + "','" + arrayTramaLectura[posLectura[0]] + "','" + arrayTramaLectura[posLectura[1]] + "','" + arrayTramaLectura[posLectura[2]] + "','" + arrayTramaLectura[posLectura[3]] + "','" + arrayTramaLectura[posLectura[4]] + "','" + arrayTramaLectura[0] + "')";


using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(pathBD))
  {
    c.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(insertBD, c))
    {
      double insertados = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (insertados > 0)
         {
          contInser++;
         }
    }
  }
}
}
 MessageBox.Show("Registros insertados: "+contInser);
 }
```

En cada iteración genero la sentencia SQL e inserto, se hace bien pero al ser un volumen considerable se demora mucho, existe forma de generar una inserción mas eficiente creando todas las sentencias y ejecutarlas en una sola transacción?

Comment: En lugar de hacer una concatenacion para armar el query, y abrir y cerrar la base de datos a cada rato, podrias hacer un Comando, preparalo, pasarle parametros y ejecutarlo. Esto haria que fuera un poco mas rapido.

Comment: intenta insertar directamente tu arrayTramaLectura  sin necesidad de iterarlo. ya que mediante un for o iteracion cualquiera es lenta.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias definir la conexion por fuera del loop `for` asi usas la misma conexion.

Ademas usa siempre parametros, no se concatena en un string los valores

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(pathBD))
{
    c.Open();

    for (int j = 0; j < arrayRespuesta.Length; j++) 
    {
        if (arrayRespuesta[j].Contains(":") && posLectura.Count > 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        string tramaLectura = arrayRespuesta[j];
        string[] arrayTramaLectura = tramaLectura.Split(new[] { "," },StringSplitOptions.None);

        string insertBD = "INSERT INTO 'Sensor'('Id_DL','id_GW','Ch1','Ch2','Ch3', ....
                            VALUES (@id, @gw);
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(insertBD, c))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id", ItemSeleccionado.idDbDataloger));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@gw", CredentialsGateway.idGateway));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id", arrayTramaLectura[posLectura[0]]));
            //resto parametros

            double insertados = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (insertados > 0)
            {
                contInser++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Con sus recomendaciones se ha reducido un poco el tiempo, pero la verdad sigue siendo muy largo, la iteracion es necesaria ya que debo ir descartando ciertos datos que no me interesan, es posible armar una matriz con los valores que deseo guardar y luego insertarla en una sola inserción?

Comment: Lo he solucionado usando una transacción y tus recomendaciones, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: si usarias Sql Server te diria que se puede ya que tene capacidad de enviar table-value como parametro a un procedure, pero sqlite es basicamente un archivo, no veo que tenga esta capacidad. igualmente de cuanto tiempos estamos hablando y que volumen de datos? porque tambien hay que ser razonable cuando se procesan archivos grandes y se requiere iterar cada linea